# How to set file to immutable for all user (Root user also) and no one can modify (Root User also)

Tags: kernel, filesystem, c, solaris

I am trying make a **immutable file** that is anyone can read only and can't do any modification  into it. i.e - **No one can** **write** into it or **delete** it or **move** it. For this is referred `chattr` [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr)  LINUX command.

```
chattr +i filename.txt
```

This command **makes file immutable** but if any other person logged into ***root*** in linux then he can remove this immutable  by

```
chattr -i filename.txt
```

So I want to make something ***script/code/command***, anything so when I make file immutable by then **only by running** these *`script/code/command`* **then and then only** file should be mutable so anyone can modify this, **otherwise not**.

Also I referred [this](https://github.com/posborne/linux-programming-interface-exercises/blob/master/15-file-attributes/chattr.c) ***`chattr`*** github code. I came to know that they used ***`ioctl`*** function and ***`flags`*** to mask this file and made immutable but I didn't find anything more except this.

There is another way to do it in 
*Solaris OS* by using `zfs` but it is not working in UBUNTU because of different platform. Is there any way to do it?

Any suggestion or solution appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how "running these script/code/command" is conceptually any different from running `chattr -i` and `chattr +i`. Fundamentally there is only one `root` account so any restriction that one person can put in place as root can be removed by anyone else who has root privileges.

Comment: @steeldriver ***You*** didn't understand my question. I know root account can make  change but my task is to root account can not make file mutable until someone (Any user or system)  run particular  ***script/code/command***  . And my task is to write this ***script/code/command*** .