# Limiting file acess only though program

Tags: permissions

In our system, we have two users "`admin`" and "`customer`", `customer` is part of group `customers`.
We need `customer` to only be able to execute certain programs which we've decided he's allowed to,  and not read *or* write to any configuration files. Said programs *can* access configuration files, but `customer` cannot interact (read/write) with them directly.
All relevant programs and config files, are stored inside `admin`.

I don't have much experience with Linux. So what I've tried is creating two programs, one that writes to file called `WriteFile`, and another which reads a file called `ReadFile`.

Both programs have the following permissions:

```
-rwx--x--- 1 admin customers ... ReadFile
-rw------- 1 admin customers ... config.txt
-rwx--x--- 1 admin customers ... WriteFile
```

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/626868) gave me an idea of using `setuid` in `ReadFile`/`WriteFile`, but whenever I tried running `setuid` as `customer` `setuid` always returned -1.

With [this question](https://superuser.com/a/835782) it seems like my only option is to give `customer` root access, which I don't really feel comfortable with.

Unless that's the only solution, is what I'm describing even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I miss a bit of the problem: what is wrong with the permissions you show? all 3 as you show now should not be editable or readable? Only executable. Mind that there is also the `-i` (immutable) it makes a file impossible to edit unless root https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198077/how-to-set-file-to-immutable-for-all-user-root-user-also-and-no-one-can-modify

Comment: Right, I don't want customer to access the file. Unless he used ReadFile or WriteFile.
The 2nd question I mentioned seems to be a fairly valid solution. 
I can give sudo permissions to customer for only a very specific file, without them needing to enter sudo passowrd.

I still need to do some more tests, to ensure that this solution fits our case